# SL(n) structures are the same as volume forms

Tags: vector-bundles, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

I saw this fact stated in many places (as Wikipedia) but I could not find a proof of it anywhere. I don't really want a rigorous proof but I'd like to get the geometric intuition behind this, since right now it makes no sense to me.

Also any references on this are appreciated.

Comment: @Andrew has got it right.  The idea is that you can always define a volume form locally (since it's just a Euclidean ball), but in order to define it globally, you need these to agree on intersections.  For that to happen, the transition between local coordinates (an element of the general linear group) must have determinant 1, since the determinant is how the volume scales.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's suppose we have that the tangent bundle $\pi:TX\to X$ is an $SL(n)$-bundle. This means, by definition, that we have an $SL(n)$-atlas $\{(U_i,\phi_i)\}_{i\in I}$, where $\phi_i: \pi^{-1}(U_i)\to U_i\times \mathbb{R}^n$ is a linear isomorphism and a homeomorphism, and moreover $\phi_i$ commutes with the projections to $U_i$, and such that the induced transition maps
$$
  \phi_{ji}: U_i\cap U_j \to GL(n),
$$
given by $x\mapsto (\phi_j)_x \circ (\phi_i)_x^{-1}$, actually land inside $SL(n)\subset GL(n)$. With this atlas in hand, we should be able to define a volume form on $X$. Indeed, we can take coordinates $x_1,\dots, x_n$ on each $U_i$ and let the volume form on $U_i$ be $v_i:=dx_1\wedge\dots\wedge dx_n$. The last thing we need to check is that these local volume forms glue into a global volume form on $X$. Well, you can check that on an overlap $U_i\cap U_j$, that the transition functions $\phi_{ji}$ induce transition functions $\tilde{\phi}_{ji}$ on $\bigwedge^n T^*X$ (imagine doing $(\phi_{ji}^{T})^{-1}$ to each vector in the wedge product). You can also check that $\tilde{\phi}_{ji} = \det(\phi_{ji})^{-1}$; in other words,
$$
  \tilde{\phi}_{ji}(v_i) = \det(\phi_{ji})^{-1} v_j.
$$
But since we have $\phi_{ji} \in SL(n)$, this determinant is $1$, and hence the $v_i$ glue into a volume form on $X$.

---

To get the rough idea of going backwards, take a volume form $v$ on $X$. In the overlap of two charts we can do a bit of linear algebra and choose transition matrices that preserve the volume form, which entails that the $\phi_{ji}$ will take values in $SL(n)$, hence giving an $SL(n)$-structure on $TX$.

Comment: Just to clarify: preserving the volume form can be done with matrices where $|det(\cdot)|=1$, and the global existence of the volume form guarantees we can always have $det(\cdot)=1$.

Answer (score 0):

A $SL(n)$ structure on a $n$-differentiable manifold $M$ is equivalent to say that the tangent bundle of $M$ has an $SL(n,\mathbb{R})$-reduction. This is equivalent to saying that there exists a coordinate change $g_{ij}$ such that the coordinates change associated to $TM$ take their value in $SL(n,\mathbb{R})$ and tis is equivalent to say that $dg_{ij}\in SL(n,\mathbb{R})$ i.e to define a volume form on $M$.

Comment: I think I need something more elaborated because I can't really see what's going on here. All these concepts are fairly new to me and I did not manage to get a good grasp on them yet. A good reference (book or notes) on the subject would be very much appreciated.